# how to make a PCA plots as I posted here

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ape-phylo

I [know how to use the PCA results to draw the circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389869/how-to-draw-circle-in-pcoa-results), but failed to draw the `x.lab` and the `y.lab` based on the plotting results from `s.class`.

How to make a plot as I posted here?
[image: two muppets]
 I would like to ask more about this.

1. How to make the points bigger or smaller according to another integer variable?
2. Can `ggplot2` draw the same circle as `s.class`? [The previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259976/colouring-a-pca-plot-by-clusters-in-r) do not show how to draw circles.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936051/adding-ellipses-to-a-principal-component-analysis-pca-plot) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039313/pca-scaling-with-ggbiplot)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size of the points cane adjusted using size. The ellipses can be added via stat_ellipsis

```
pca <- prcomp(iris[iris$Species %in% c("virginica","versicolor"),1:4], retx = TRUE,  scale = TRUE,tol=0.4)
predicted <-predict(pca,iris[,1:4])
ggplot(data.frame(predicted))+aes(x=PC1,y=PC2,color=iris$Species)+geom_point(aes(size=iris$Sepal.Length))+stat_ellipse()+stat_ellipse(level=0.8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What I did in the [`pcoa`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anpefi/msap/master/pkg/msap/R/pcoa.R) function of my [`msap`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/msap/index.html) package was to use `s.class` only for the ellipses and centroids:

1. Add empty plot, with labels and limits depending on several variables:

   ```
   plot(0,0, main=paste(name,surname, sep=": "), type = "n",
     xlab=paste("C1 (",var1,"%)"),ylab=paste("C2 (",var2,"%)"), 
     xlim=c(minX-10^floor(log10(abs(minX))),maxX+10^floor(log10(abs(maxX)))), 
     ylim=c(minY-10^floor(log10(abs(minY))),maxY+10^floor(log10(abs(maxY)))),
    frame=TRUE, cex=1.5)
   ```

   Look at the xlab.
2. Plot the points for the different treatments/groups with different colors/simbols. **Here you could set the points size using the cex parameter**.

   ```
   for(i in 1:ntt){
       points(spcoo[[i]], pch=21, col="black", bg=bgcolors[i])
   }
   ```
3. Finally use ade4's c.class to plot ellipses, stars and group labels, but not the points (cpoint=0)

   ```
   s.class(pcol$points, groups, cpoint=0, col=bgcolors, add.plot=TRUE)
   ```

In my code I get a figure like this PCOA figure:

[image]